# How to Nest Value Side of Dictionary in Array Using PHP with JSON_decode and JSON_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, dictionary

On the client side to comply with a whole bunch of complicated legacy code, I need JSON to look like this:

```
A. {"book":[{"title":"War and Peace.","author":"Leo Tolstoy"}]}
```

where the "value" side of the Dictionary is an array containing a dictionary e.g. `[{}]`.

However, when retrieving a random item, my server code is outputting the following:

```
B. {"book":{"title":"War and Peace","author":"Leo Tolstoy"}}
```

where the "value" side is just a dictionary e.g. `{}`.

How can I generate the JSON so it looks like A instead of B?

Here is what is currently happening on the server to generate B:
The data is actually stored in JSON as:

```
$str = '[{"title":"War and Peace","author":"Leo Tolstoy"}]';

The code that outputs a random item is:

$array = json_decode($str, true); 
$rand = $array[array_rand($array)];
echo json_encode(array('book'=>$rand));
```

How can I put the dictionary on the value side inside square brackets e.g. `[{}]`?

Comment: Literally `['book' => [$rand]]`. Just one more array around your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply wrap you `$rand` variable inside bracket `[]`. Curious to know **What is the purpose of `array_rand()` here?**

```
<?php 
$str = '[{"title":"War and Peace","author":"Leo Tolstoy"}]';
$array = json_decode($str, true); 
$rand = $array[array_rand($array)];
echo json_encode(array('book'=>[$rand]));
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/dZJRn

Comment: For older ersions of PHP I think you need to use array($rand) instead of just adding brackets.

Comment: Yes  `[]` is supported in PHP >= 5.4, for old legacy program you can use array() instead of []